Split array strictly in two parts where left half elements are smaller right half elements
I need to divide the array A [n] into two sub-arrays A1, A2 based on the middle value midval, in a manner that all the elements of A1 (or denoted left) are smaller than the midval and all the elements of A2 (or denoted as right) are greater than the (midval).
Reference for the First partition phase i am implementing: https://thescipub.com/pdf/jcssp.2008.897.902.pdf
I wrote this code which is working but it doesn't separate it stritcly left half is smaller than right half.
        int pivot = data.Length / 2;

        // Find the max and min values for left and right parts
        int Lmax = int.MinValue, Lmin = int.MaxValue, Rmax = int.MinValue, Rmin = int.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < pivot; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] > Lmax)
                Lmax = data[i];
            if (data[i] < Lmin)
                Lmin = data[i];
        }
        for (int i = pivot; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] > Rmax)
                Rmax = data[i];
            if (data[i] < Rmin)
                Rmin = data[i];
        }

        // Calculate midval
        int midval = (Lmax + Lmin + Rmax + Rmin) / 4;

        // Perform swaps
        for (int i = 0, j = data.Length - 1; i < pivot && j >= pivot;)
        {

            if (data[i] >= midval && data[j] < midval)
            {
                int temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
            else if(data[i] < midval)
            {
                i++;
            }
            else if(data[j] >= midval)
            {
                j--;
            }
        }

I am calculating midval value which must always be more or equal all values in the left half and less than all array element in the right half. And after I swap elements from left half and right half: if element from left half is more than midval with element from right half if it is less than midval.
In this way it swaps elements in the right way, but it doesnt divide array on two equal halfs that 0 to n/2 elements are always less than n/2 to n elements.
It stops swapping close to n/2 from both sides, but stops because one of pointers reaches n/2 range and some values close to middle are left without swapping.
For example left pointers reached n/2 and all elements are less than midval, but right pointer is on position n/2+10 and in the middle we have 10 elements which are not checked and in that 10 elements we have that one, which are less  than midval.
I think the problem is in not correct midval calculation and it should be replaced by different formula, am i right?

How is this different than just sorting an array and then splitting it at the middle? Also, I think you cannot guarantee "left half is smaller than right half" since in an array with an odd number of elements one of the half must have n and the other n+1 elements (i.e., an array with 5 elements will have one "half" with 2 elements and the other "half" with 3 elements).

"not correct midval calculation" - you are right, but there is no formula. You need to find a median, and you cannot do so just by comparing ranges.

@topsail yes you are right, if the size of array is odd i would have two parts where left one contains n/2 elements and the right one n/2 + 1 or vice versa.
And about sorting, yes it will work, but i need especially just swapping elements, without using sorting

What if an array had values all the same ... how would you satisfy the condition that the left half have all have values less then the right half? I don't think the authors of the paper wrote very clearly (although my skill with this kind of notation is poor). What does if A[0] = Lmax > midval mean? Whether you do the = first or the > first, we end up with a boolean compared to a number and I just don't get it.
